# SYNERGY ERROR MESSAGE: cannot listen for clients: cannot bind address: Address already in use

Tags: linux, windows, networking, synergy

I've had synergy for a couple months. It works great between my PC (windows 10) and my laptop (also windows 10). However, I have another hard drive in PC that uses linux, and I can't seem to get my computer to work with synergy when I'm using the linux hard drive in my PC and my windows laptop. I always get the error message "WARNING: cannot listen for clients: cannot bind address: Address already in use" Anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3):

The part where it says:

# Address already in use

Another program (maybe another copy of synergy) is using the synergy port; stop the other program or choose a different port in the Advanced dialog.

To see which applications have open ports, On Linux:

#netstat -tupan

On Windows:

Start>>All Programs>>Accessories>>System Tools>>Resource Monitor
or Run resmon.exe, or from TaskManager performance tab

Comment: In my case `ps aux | grep synergy` showed that I had two instances open on my Ubuntu host. I must have killed the wrong one, so I ended up just closing all of them and then opening one and it fixed itself.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to avoid rebooting as follows:

```
ps aux | grep synergys
```

Which will provide you with the pid, or process id, which you can then kill.

```
kill -9 1234
```

Be sure to substitute your pid for the "1234" above.

Then, restart synergy, and check that the server_ip has not changed on any connected machines.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the David's answer, if found multiple instances,
try killing by # kill "process id".

Process id is the first column when I run

### netstat -tupan.

But it might happen that it won't kill the last instance( it didn't on my system ubuntu 18.04).

Try rebooting both client and server.
If you have gui open the it on both the systems and select the server and client.
while server set-up use existing configuration and choose .config file for synergy which you were using earlier .synergy.conf
if you are not sure where to find it use #find

### find -type f -name ".*.conf"

For more about synergy configuration file refer to this [synergy_config](https://moonbse.github.io/Synergy_setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following (requires `sudo apt install htop`):
`htop`
Hit **F3** to search for *synergy*. Keep killing processes with **F9** until no more matches when searching. Then `synergy` worked again.